# Persistent "A network changed" in Chrome

Tags: networking, google-chrome

I constantly get the error:

`Your connection was interrupted
ERR_NETWORK_CHANGED`

This happens on chrome while the internet works fine on Mozilla Firefox.
Since this has been happening, I noticed something else too.
Now when I hover over the wifi button in the top right corner (Ubuntu 16.04), instead of the sleek drop down I get a very broad one which shows ethernet network disconnected and all, while I haven't connected LAN.

[image]

I tried putting the IPv6 configuration to ignore in the network but that doesn't help. Any help is appreciated.

UPDATE: I don't know if it is a coincidence but this might be happening after I launch google's syntaxnet as a python subprocess through docker. I don't know if they are related or not but I think this has been happening since I started the above. I could be wrong on this.

Thank you.

^ This weird thing happens only when am running a docker container or something!

Comment: My Ubuntu-using colleagues are experiencing the same thing. I still have no idea how to solve it. They're all using Docker daily as well.